# Trouble with color datagridview

Tags: c#

I have DataGridView on my form and I'm trying to color cell.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dtToGrid = new DataTable();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dtToGrid.Columns.Add("Group");

            DataRow dr;

            dr = dtToGrid.NewRow();
            dr["Group"] = "must become lightGreen";

            dtToGrid.Rows.Add(dr);        

            bs.DataSource = dtToGrid;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

            ColorData();

            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

        public void ColorData()
        {
            dataGridView1[0, 0].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorData();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, function ColorData invoke twice, but when it's invoked from constructor - nothing happens and cell is still white. Invoke from button1_Click, which is event-function, colors cell correctly.

What's the matter?

Comment: what class is the object dataGridView1?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365617/how-to-force-refresh-the-datagridviews-content) Check the answer on the link.
dataGridView1.EndEdit();   will probably do the trick since you're changing stuff you're editing.

Comment: Try swap ColorData() to before the DataSource assigning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.
First - the form should load and only after that you can change cell's color.
I change color in event-function Load for the main form and everything works.