# Clear all the values and load it again in DataGridView (refresh)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am a .net beginner. I want to refresh all the values in a datagridview.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml"); /* XML file */
 dgvMain.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I am trying the below code to refresh(*not working*)

**onButtonClick**

```
dgvMain.DataSource = null;
dgvMain.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I think I am missing something in the above code.

I even tried `dgvMain.Refresh();` (i dont know anything about this. saw it in intellisense)

The other codes i tried are: (*not working*)

```
dgvMain.Rows.Clear(); /*ERROR: Cannot clear this list.*/
```

`dgvMain.EndEdit();`  [no change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390312/1577396)

`this.BindingContext[this.dgvMain.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
            this.dgvMain.Refresh();
            this.dgvMain.Parent.Refresh();`  [no change](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3/)

Please assist 

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What happend on button click. Did you change some values in DataSet?

Comment: no i am not changing the dataset values. I am changing xml file instead through some backend application

Comment: Well, you need to refresh data in DataTable within DataSet

Comment: i am not using datatable also. as i shown in the code.

Comment: ds.Tables[0] from you code. You need to refresh this DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you notice in one of your comments, you changed xml file with some backend application. So, each time when you click on button, you need to reload xml file:

```
**onButtonClick**

ds.Clear();
ds.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must call dgvMain.DataBind(); in order to bind the data in the new way that you described.  If that does not work then I would bind the data to a empty set and then call DataBind();